# Creating a 4x5 Image Grid using HTML& CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a 4x5 image grid. But I'm unable to get the images to align up properly. And have the correct responsive size. I'm trying to create something like this [dealsource.tech](http://dealsource.tech). Feel like I'm failing really hard it. 
Any insight will be really helpful.

```css
.row-one {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 0px;
  margin-left: -2.5%;
}

.row-one li {
  display:inline-block;;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 2.5% 2.5%;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-szie: 1rem;
  vertical-align: top;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ddd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.product-image img {
  max-width: 50%;
  height:auto;
  margin:0 0 10px;
}

.product-description h3 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
}

.product-description p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: .9em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-three">
 <ul class="row-one">
  <li>
   <figure class="product-image"><img src="images/graphics cards/Asus GeForce GTX2.jpg" alt="Asus GeForce GTX2"></figure>
   <figcaption class="product-description"><h3>Asus GeForce GTX2</h3>
    <p>From $800 to <em>$500</em></p>
    <p>Dec 29, 2016</p></figcaption>
  </li>
  <li>
   <figure class="product-image"><img src="images/graphics cards/Gigabyte GT 420.jpg" alt="Gigabyte GT 420"></figure>
   <div class="product-description"><h3>Asus GeForce GTX2</h3>
    <p>From $800 to <em>$500</em></p>
    <p>Dec 29, 2016</p></div>
  </li>
  <li>
   <figure class="product-image"><img src="images/graphics cards/Gigabyte Geforce GTX 1050.jpg" alt="Gigabyte Geforce GTX 1050"></figure>
   <figcaption class="product-description"><h3>Asus GeForce GTX2</h3>
    <p>From $800 to <em>$500</em></p>
    <p>Dec 29, 2016</p></div></figcaption>
  </li>
  <li>
   <figure class="product-image"><img src="images/graphics cards/Gigabyte     GT 420.jpg" alt="Gigabyte GT 420"></figure>
   <div class="product-description"><h3>Asus GeForce GTX2</h3>
    <p>From $800 to <em>$500</em></p>
    <p>Dec 29, 2016</p></div>
  </li>
 </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a "4x5 layout"? That doesn't match what your example site shows.

Comment: The end result will be 4x5. Until I can fix the spacing issue, I only have code for a 4x1.

Comment: You need to repeat a row of 4, 5 times. I noticed some missing close tags so also validate your html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is through `flex-box`

https://jsfiddle.net/ASAP/qbxtgmf0/1/

```
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 440px; /* 4 items * item width(100+5+5) = 440 */
}

.flexbox .flex-item {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, saved me allot of time and frustration!

Comment: No problem, also please accept the best answer if any of the answers helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Images are hard to control their position as they are inline elements. You can use `<div>` instead or set the `display` property of the images to `block`.

Answer (score 0):

That `product-image` class only contains the images you want to resize and does not reference the images in question. In order to properly do so, you should instead use a `div` tag like `div id="product-image"` and set the `height` and `width` properties to whatever you want.